# Taylor or Maclaurin series for the factorial function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am new to Taylor/Maclaurin series and want to know if there is a series representation for the factorial function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the standard factorial function $!:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$, a Taylor series cannot exist because $\mathbb{N}$ has no accumulation points so you cannot take derivatives of it. To see this, you could try evaluating the following difference quotient:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow n}\frac{x!-n!}{x-n}.$$

Immediately you can see this limit is not well-posed because the factorial only takes integer values. You can't have $1.00001!$ for instance so you can't get arbitrary close to $n$.

You need some way to extend the idea of a factorial to the real numbers in order to take derivatives. One such generalization of the factorial to (almost all) real numbers is the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). For natural numbers, we have that $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ and you can show this pretty easily. In this case, derivatives of all orders exist and you can have a Taylor series by evaluating around a certain point (that is not $0$ or a negative integer since the Gamma function is not defined for them).